# Ajax.BeginForm not updating target div

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Edit(string temp)
{
     ViewBag.Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
     return PartialView("Edit");
}
```

**Partial View:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId = "mydiv"}))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    }
```

**Index View** (part of contents)

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <span>The Time is: @ViewBag.Time</span>
</div>
@Html.Partial("Edit")
```

`ClientValidationEnabled` and `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` are `true`
`jquery.validate.min.js`, `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js`, `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`, `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js` and `MicrosoftAjax.js` are added

At first, the time is shown correctly. When the Save button is clicked for the first time, time disappears and Save button is shown twice and then nothing happens except calling the Action on clicking on both buttons.

Comment: You may want to set the InsertionMode to replace as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have things kind of backwards. Try this:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(string temp)   
{  
    ViewBag.Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");  
    return PartialView("Edit");   
}
```

**Index View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", new AjaxOptions{UpdateTargetId = "mydiv"}))     
    {     
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />     
    }            
@Html.Action("Edit")
```

**Partial View (Edit)**

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <span>The Time is: @ViewBag.Time</span> 
</div>
```

The ViewBag is only accessable at runtime (when the page initially loads) so this means if you fetch data via ajax, the viewbag in the controller action is only accessable to the partial view of that controller action (and not index.cshtml which called the action via ajax). In short (tl;dr) to be able to use the viewbag which you set in Edit action, you need to use it in the returning partialview. (and not anywhere else, because the content isnt re-rendered by the razor engine)

Comment: Though i have not tried your solution but what is obsolete here?. Why cant i have the form within my partial view and update the div within the index view? What is the logic behind?

Comment: Because 1. Why would you want to fetch a form multiple times? The form never changes, the form doesnt have different data each time you fetch it, its always the same data. Thats why you might as well have it in the main view, and not in a view which is fetched via ajax. 2. The ViewBag is only accessable at runtime (when the page initially loads) so this means if you fetch data via ajax, the viewbag in the controller action is only accessable to the partial view of that controller action (and not index.cshtml which called the action via ajax)

Comment: In short (tl;dr) to be able to use the viewbag which you set in Edit action, you need to use it in the returning partialview. (and not anywhere else)

Comment: I think you have missed the idea of having `UpdateTargetId`, try your solution without having `AjaxOptions` and the div, it will still work i think

Comment: No, because in my solution the div's content with id "mydiv" will be replaced with the partial views content each time it is submitted. And thus rendering the time correctly just like you wanted. In your problem you render a new instance of the form each time you click on the submit button, and the time never gets updated because the Viewbag cant be rendered anywhere because the partial view doesnt use it. Im sorry if im not making myself clear here.

Comment: Please notice that im not using the same order as you, (you have controller, partial view, and index) I have controller. index and then partial view. Just in case you got mixed up

Comment: have you tried your solution without AjaxOptions because it looks the Ajax is calling the Controller and controller is rendering the partial view directly instead of Ajax updating the mydiv

Comment: See my updated answer, this is exactly how I'm using it on my site.

Answer (score -1):

```
I set things up like so.
```

Very simple, but I noticed the person posting the 
question and the answer had no insertion mode so I posted this lame bit of code :)

```
 {
                                                                            HttpMethod = "post",
                                                                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                                            UpdateTargetId = "the div youwant to update / replace"
                                                                        }
```